# Hg convert fails with: "abort: unknown revision <nodeid>!"

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

How can I figure out how to debug the following issue given the scenario? I have previously run `hg convert` on the source and target repos and all worked fine. I'm running it again to convert new changesets from the source.

## Version

Mercurial 2.7.1

## Command

```
hg convert HgSourceRepo HgTargetRepo --filemap DirNameRemap --verbose --debug
```

## Filemap "DirNameRemap"

```
include .
rename src src/SubProj
```

## shamap

```
0370cf235b9844445ddbd0570b51df8ab4cfbfe9 4bb51586a76b0c8071fff389dc6a1178505ab59b
... 
15a1d031f3bdd0b930645785d58586347365f65b e781c32e5aef538930c5c52beda8ac2a2e6adc6e
```

## Result

```
run hg source pre-conversion action
run hg sink pre-conversion action
scanning source...
scanning: 1 revisions
scanning: 2 revisions
scanning: 3 revisions
scanning: 4 revisions
scanning: 5 revisions
scanning: 6 revisions
scanning: 7 revisions
scanning: 8 revisions
sorting...
converting...
7 Added tests 
source: 15a1d031f3bdd0b930645785d58586347365f65b
converting: 0/8 revisions (0.00%)

// ...

6 Merge with AddingMetadata
source: f4a8ef2059633068ac49f51f7923d78031732a58
converting: 1/8 revisions (12.50%)
run hg sink post-conversion action
run hg source post-conversion action
abort: unknown revision '4bb51586a76b0c8071fff389dc6a1178505ab59b'!  <----- What?
```

Comment: Silly question, but I assume that the unknown revision (`4bb51586a...`) actually exists in `HgTargetRepo`?  I don't tend to use `convert`, but as I understand it, `shamap` contains previously-mapped changeset ids?

Comment: It does, on both counts: the target exists and shamap is a map of source to target changeset ids.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by upgrading to 2.9.1